# GLSL 410 default layout qualifier

Tags: opengl

I was putting together a small demo in OpenGL 4.1 last night and accidentally omitted the layout qualifier for my vertex positions:

```
layout(location = 0) in vec3 position;
```

Even though I forgot this line in my vertex shader, everything worked as normal.  I was only using a single attribute, by the way.  Is this behavior in the standard or did I just get lucky in my implementation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The GLSL standard says

> If a vertex shader input variable with no location assigned in the shader text has a location specified 
>   through the OpenGL API, the API-assigned location will be used.  **Otherwise, such variables will be 
>   assigned a location by the linker**.

So the question becomes about the rest of your program. Were there any calls to `glBindAttribLocation` or `glGetAttribLocation​`?

If not you got lucky. Here's what OpenGL 4.1 core says (sect 2.11):

> When a program is linked,  any active attributes without a binding specified either through BindAttribLocation or explicitly set within the shader text will automatically be bound to vertex attributes by the GL. Such bindings can be queried using the command GetAttribLocation.
>   LinkProgram will fail if the assigned binding  of  an  active  attribute  variable  would  cause  the  GL  to  reference  a  non-existent generic attribute (one greater than or equal to the value of MAX_VERTEX_ATTRIBS).

and a skim of the rest of the spec reveals an absence of discussion about attribute location allocation, meaning that it is up to some undefined mechanism to choose the binding.

Comment: Holy cow, that's weird.  I didn't use glBindAttribLocation or glGetAttribLoaction.  Buuuuuut, just realized the library I was using (openFrameworks) may have been doing that behind the scenes.  That's probably what it was, thanks for the tip!  That linker-assigned location behavior seems like bug city, I wish GLSL mandated the explicit layout approach.

Comment: That being said I simply can't imagine an implementation doing anything other than starting at 0 and incrementing